# Selecting wide object rim in image in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

I have images of a tumor from MRI and i'm doing some post-processing (pixel-by-pixel model fitting etc). Due to low contrast i'm selecting a tumor by hand (using roipoly). I need to divide my selected tumor into periphery (about 10 pixels wide) and the center (the rest of a tumor). I can do this using roipoly, but this wouldn't be so precise and in every tumor the rim would be a little bit different. I'm looking for some modification of edge detection which could detect a region exactly 10 pixels smaller then selected by me object (tumor).

Comment: Yeah! I like to perform erosion of my tumor mask by 10 pixels. Tumor is of course irregular.

Comment: My answer is about the generic technique. The problem might be of your specific boundary being very snake-y. For this you might have to consider reading papers and similar complex techniques

Comment: For your question to be attractive and useful to the community, can I interest you in adding sample images (source image, segmented, desired result) and what you have tried (brief code overview) ?

Answer (score 2):

## Erosion (morphological operation)

You have a binary image with your segmentation as True, and want the 10px wide border between True and False ?

**You just need to erode your mask by 10 px, then substract it from original mask.**

In pseudocode :

```
border = mask - erosion(mask,10)
```

[image: Eroded image]

More about [morphological operations](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/morops.htm)

Matlab related details at [Matlab morphology documentation](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/morphology-fundamentals-dilation-and-erosion.html).